# Need a Regex rule that will take the lower number of a range, drop plus sign, interpret dates as zero

Tags: regex

I'm dealing with a .csv file using a [webscraping plugin](https://www.webscraper.io/) for Chrome.  The supplier provides the following types of values for product stock quantity. Each specific case is an instance of a more generalised case which follows the format that it exemplifies:

- 20-25 (supplier has between 20-25 units)
- 50+ (supplier has 50 or more units)
- 1-Nov (supplier anticipates stock on 1st of Nov)
- Nov-1 (supplier anticipates stock on 1st of Nov)

This makes my life difficult, because I must prepare the resulting .csv file so that each of the above scenarios translates respectively into a single number:

- 20 (take the lower number of the range to be the stock quantity)
- 50 (drop the plus sign)
- 0 (if stock is estimated to arrive on 1-Nov, then currently it's zero)
- 0 (if stock is estimated to arrive on Nov-1, then currently it's zero)

I have one tool and one tool only at my disposal to translate the original values above - for the plugin  [accepts regex rules](https://www.webscraper.io/documentation#text-selector).
[image]

Could you please devise a regex rule for me which would achieve the above?

Comment: am I right to assume the first number in `20-25` is always the lower number? I don't see a need to extract the lower value, maybe just the first number would do the job.

Comment: Yes, I'm willing to accept the first value, although bonus brownie points if you can extract the lower value of the two as it is safer and less assuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure regex engines cannot return something than is not in the input, so returning `0` for `1-Nov` and `Nov-1` is not an option. But returning nothing is quite possible and I hope it will be enough for you.

Here is the regex I came up with:

```
^\d+(?=\+|-\d+)
```

Explanation:

- `\d+` matches one or more digits (0, 1, 2, ..., 9);
- `(?=...) is called [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html);
- `\+|-\d+` matches a literal `+`, or a literal `-` followed by at least one digit. Since it is inside a positive lookahead the regex engine will only **check** that the input matches and not return that part of the match (I can only advise you to visit the link above if you wish to understand more about positive lookaheads).

Tested on your input:

- `20-50` --> `20`
- `50+` --> `50`
- `1-Nov` --> ø
- `Nov-1` --> ø

Comment: Could you please also provide a variation of the solution where the regex rule selects the second value of a range, rather than the first value?  Thanks!

Comment: The best I can come up with: `(?<=\d-)\d+|\d+(?=\+)`. It uses both positive lookahead and negative lookbehind which are both explained at the link I provide in my answer.